# Javascript - Local Storage

Tags: javascript

I would like to hide and show DIVS again.
unfortunately saving in local storage does not work when I reload the page.

```js
function toggleElementDisplay(name) {
    var divs = document.getElementsByName(name), 
    closed_divs = document.getElementById(localStorage.closed_divs);
    if (closed_divs && closed_divs !== divs) {
        closed_divs.style.display = 'none';
    }

    for(i=0; i < divs.length; i++) {
       divs[i].style.display = (divs[i].style.display=="none") ? "block" : "none";
    }
    localStorage.closed_divs = divs;
};

if (localStorage.closed_divs) {
    toggleElementDisplay(localStorage.closed_divs);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not right way to use localStorage api. localStorage expose getItem and setItem methods. You have to use those to set and get values

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Local storage does not work with the `.attribute` syntax. Instead, use `localStorage.getItem('closed_divs')` and `localStorage.setItem('closed_divs', divs)`. This way the data will persist on page reload.